# CODEIGNITER 3: save a whole page response to a file before sending it to client browser

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to save a page to a file in CODEIGNITER 3 - a whole page just before the page is sent to a browser. But I don't know how to do it and the most important is where to process the page in Codeigniter 3 code?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I was lucky to find it somehow in my code:

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html?highlight=display_override

> display_override Overrides the _display() method, used to send the
> finalized page to the web browser at the end of system execution. This
> permits you to use your own display methodology. Note that you will
> need to reference the CI superobject with $this->CI =& get_instance()
> and then the finalized data will be available by calling
> $this->CI->output->get_output().